# How to call a service url for POST while passing body parameter in asp.net mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net mvc
I have a service url, I have tested it in postman..it is showing me the result.[image: snapshot of the body parameter]

But I am unable to understand, how can I pass the Body parameter programatically in the controller while calling the service.

I have tried like this:

string reqData = "{ \"Text\":\""+text+"\""+ ",\"UserID\" : \"10098\",\"EventID\":\"42\"}";

Please help, as I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get data with http request in service.

```
getFunction(){
    return this.http.get('URL')
          .map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in the frontside,

```
this.'servicename'.getFunction().subscribe(x=>{ 
      this.x = x;
    });
```